# monitoring jira by zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, jira

Anybody knows, how monitoring Jira by zabbix. In Jira some customer can create tickek when send mail on specify mailbox who is connected to Jira and to specify project. Please tell me how monitoring or ticket inserted correctly in project.

Please give me some advice

Regards
Mick

Answer (score 1):

Define "correctly". Because jira deletes mails after processing them, I consider it correct enough to monitor the size of the jira mailboxes. If there are mails in those that are older than 10 minutes, or more than 25 mails in total, we consider it a problem and alert.

Comment: Ok and it would be possible to monitor whether the project there is a new ticket?. For example we monitor one project and when ticket are be created zabbix send notification for us.

Comment: Sure, all that information is in a database. So just query it :)